# Windows Защитник "нашел" троян в моей программе (Телеграмм бот)

Tags: java, windows, telegram-bot

Написал на `java` телеграмм бота, экспортировал в `jar`, поставил его в автозагрузку.
Но `Windows Защитник` "обнаружил" там троян. Мог ли троян там появиться в моей программе, или Windows ошибся.

[image: картинка]

Comment: Не мог. Архив не подписан, вот и ругается

Comment: А как подписать (экспортировал через Eclipse)?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/signing.html